# Are the events in Black Gold based on fact?

Tags: historical-accuracy, black-gold

The history of which country is depicted in the movie [Black Gold](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1701210/)? Is it Qatar?

It seems to be, considering the movie is made by France | Italy | Qatar | Tunisia :D And Qatar Being the richest country and everything...

Or maybe it's just made up stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the movie is based on the 1957 novel **"South of the Heart: a novel of modern Arabia"** by [Hans Ruesch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Ruesch).

As far as I could find out the novel is not depicting any actual events or wars. The principalities "Hobeika" and "Salmaah" did not actually exist, and the conflict between them is unlikely to be based on a real one according to this [german historical movie site](http://historienschinken.de/?p=914).

The daily life of the people in this region around 1930 are very likely to be historically accurate though.